# Sonar cloud code coverage saying partially covered by tests, however there are no conditions on that line

Tags: typescript, code-coverage, sonarlint

In sonar cloud code coverage, the sonar is displaying the following error on the highlighted code line

> Partially covered by tests (8 of 10 conditions).

```
deleteCostGroupInternal(cost: CostItemViewModel){
    this.itemsValue.splice(this.itemsValue.indexOf(cost), 1);
    if (!this.itemsValue.find(c => c.costType.id === cost.costType.id)) {
        **cost.costGroup.deleteCostType(cost.costType.id);**
    }
    if (!this.itemsValue.find(c => c.costGroup.id === cost.costGroup.id)) {
        this.costGroupsValue.delete(cost.costGroup.id);
    }
    this.changeSubject.next();
}
```

As can be seen in the code there are no conditions  on that line. Can somebody please tell which conditions sonar cloud might referring to?
I have scratched my head for too much time already and found no solution.
My pull request is blocked due to this silly issue.